# Proper usage of ResourceBundle

Tags: java

I’ve never used ResourceBundle before.

I have a simple Google Play Scraper (uses Jsoup library) which I want to customize and introduce
multilingual support.

I have some classes. First you have to get html Document to parse later.

GooglePlayConnection class (provides Connection, then I just need to invoke method get()):

```
public class GooglePlayConnection {

    /**
     * Typical base part of URL for all apps.
     */
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?";

    private final String language;

    private final String country;

    public GooglePlayConnection(String language, String country) {
        this.language = language;
        this.country = country;
    }

    /**
     * Tries to connect to provided URL. Uses localized version of URL that retrieves from {@link #getLocalized(Map, String, String)}.
     * Also checks if URL applies to APPS category to prevent from parsing books/music/movies.
     */
    public Connection connect(String URL) throws InvalidGooglePlayUrlException, MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {
        final java.net.URL url= new URL(URL);
        if (GooglePlayCorrectURL.isUrlValid(url)) {
            if (!url.getPath().contains("apps")) {
                throw new InvalidGooglePlayUrlException("Wrong Google Play category");
            }
            Map<String, String> params = getParameters(URL);
            URL = getLocalized(params, language, country).toString();
            return Jsoup.connect(URL);
        }
        else {
            throw new InvalidGooglePlayUrlException("Not Google Play URL");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets localized version of provided URL.
     */
    private URL getLocalized(Map<String, String> params, String language, String country) throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(BASE_URL)
                .addParameter("id", params.get("id"))
                .addParameter("hl", language)
                .addParameter("gl", country);
        return uriBuilder.build().toURL();
    }

    private Map<String, String> getParameters(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
        return Arrays.stream(new URL(url).getQuery().split("&"))
                .map(s -> s.split("="))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k[0], v -> v.length > 1 ? v[1] : ""));
    }
```

Scraper:

```
public class GooglePlayAppsScraper {

    /**
     * Default language system settings to determine in which language to analyze HTML document.
     */
    private static final ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("patterns", Locale.getDefault());

    /**
     * CSS-like element selectors that find elements matching a query.
     */
    private static final String CURRENT_VERSION = resourceBundle.getString("game.currentVersion");

    private static final String REQUIREMENTS = resourceBundle.getString("game.requirements");

    public String getCurrentVersion(Document htmlDocument) {
        return getIfAttributePresent(CURRENT_VERSION, htmlDocument);
    }

    public String getRequirements(Document htmlDocument) {
        return getIfAttributePresent(REQUIREMENTS, htmlDocument);
    }
    ...
```

And I've some bundles with different languages, like this:

```
//en
game.currentVersion = div:matchesOwn(^Current Version$)
game.lastUpdate = div:matchesOwn(^Updated$)
game.installs = div:matchesOwn(^Installs$)
game.requirements = div:matchesOwn(^Requires Android$)
...
```

```
//ru
game.currentVersion = div:matchesOwn(^Текущая версия$)
game.lastUpdate = div:matchesOwn(^Обновлено$)
game.installs = div:matchesOwn(^Количество установок$)
game.requirements = div:matchesOwn(^Требуемая версия Android$)
...
```

What's important? I need to "transfer" information about language to my scraper. To search elements the language in the document must match the one that the scraper will use.

I don't want to pass these parameters to each scraper method. It will looks like:

```
public String getRequirements(Document htmlDocument, String language) {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("patterns", Locale.forLanguageTag(language));
        String requirements = resourceBundle.getString("game.requirements");
        return getIfAttributePresent(requirements, htmlDocument);
    }
```

I created LanguageSettings:

```
public class LanguageSettings {

    private static Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();

    public static Map<String, String> getSettings() {
        return settings;
    }

    public static void setSettings(Map<String, String> settings) {
        LanguageSettings.settings = settings;
    }
}
```

Then update connection:

```
    private final String language;

    private final String country;

    public GooglePlayConnection(String language, String country) {
        this.language = language;
        this.country = country;
        LanguageSettings.getSettings().put("language", language);
    }
```

Then update scraper:

```
private static final ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("patterns", Locale.forLanguageTag(LanguageSettings.getSettings().get("language")));
```

Simple usage:

```
String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.playdigious.cultist";
Document document = new GooglePlayConnection("en", "US").connect(url).get();
GooglePlayAppsScraper scraper = new GooglePlayAppsScraper();
System.out.println(scraper.getPrice(document));
```

This will work if done in the right order (like in the example), but I'm sure there is a better solution.

How should I connect my scraper and connection to one ResourceBundle in the proper way?

Answer (score 1):

One problem here that I immediately see you expressed yourself: your code should be invoked in the right order for it to work.

What this means is your components have a shared state that they don't state upfront (the `ResourceBundle` and `LanguageSettings`), and the `GooglePlayAppsScraper` is even built in such way that all prior operations must be gone before this class ever gets loaded - because it accesses the `LanguageSettings` statically and saves result in a `static final` field, its initialization will be done once per the app lifecycle (not quite, but close to), when the class gets loaded from disk. If you don't initialize correctly, then it, at least, fails pretty fast with a `NullPointerException`, but we can do better.

What I think is a better approach is to get rid of static state in there.
I suggest making `LanguageSettings` a more apparent part of the whole system.

First, make it an object:

```
public class LanguageSettings {
    private String languageTag;
    private String country;

     public LanguageSettings(String language, String country) {
         this.languageTag = Objects.requireNonNull(language, "languageTag");
         this.country = Objects.requireNonNull(country, "country");
     }

     public String getLanguageTag() {
         return languageTag;
     }

     public String getCountry() {
         return country;
     }
}
```

Then, make `GoogleConnection` depend on it:

```
public class GoogleConnection {
    private LanguageSettings settings;

    public GoogleConnection(LanguageSettings settings) {
        this.settings = Objects.requireNonNull(settings);
    }
    <...snip...>
    private URL getLocalized(Map<String, String> params) throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(BASE_URL)
            .addParameter("id", params.get("id"))
            .addParameter("hl", settings.getLanguageTag())
            .addParameter("gl", settings.getCountry());
        return uriBuilder.build().toURL();
    }
}
```

And also, make `GooglePlayAppsScraper` dependent on the same `LanguageSettings` object for initialization:

```
public class GooglePlayAppsScraper {
    private ResourceBundle bundle;

    /*
     *  Notice here: I am not reading from bundle, these are now simple constants
     */
    private static final String CURRENT_VERSION = "game.currentVersion";

    private static final String REQUIREMENTS = "game.requirements";

    public GooglePlayAppsScraper(LanguageSettings settings) {
        this.bundle = initBundle(settings);
    }

    private ResourceBundle initBundle(LanguageSettings settings) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(settings);
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle("patterns", Locale.forLanguageTag(settings.getLanguageTag());
    }

    public String getRequirements(Document htmlDocument) {
        return getIfAttributePresent(bundle.getString(REQUIREMENTS), htmlDocument);
    }
}
```

Advantages of doing it this way - the "right way" to invoke your code is essentially now the only way it can be done - unless you already have `LanguageSettings` object, you can't initialize neither `GooglePlayAppsScraper`, nor `GoogleConnection`. And when you do (assuming you supply the same object for both), it will always initialize correctly, it's not as easy to swap two lines of code and get exceptions because of it.
Your app will also now support running several connections and scrapers in parallel (assuming this is something you want and external services allow it) - and scrapers can even have different language settings (they couldn't before because `Settings` was a per-app state).